# How to get an image from the server with django and graphql?

Tags: django, image, file, get, graphql

I already managed to make the mutations to upload, update and print the images. But how can I get the images files on in base64 in the query?

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="uploads/images")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Did you consider returning the path to the image in graphql? I ask because ImageField stores the string path to the image file in the media directory as configured by your settings.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for comment. I wanted to return the file with the image in the query. I will post my request right now.

Answer (score 0):

I write my own solution.
First I created a new field in the ImageType object to store the image file in base 64. Additionally I validated that the value of the image field existed and the written address was associated with an existing file on the hard disk.
Then when the image is requested a new field called base64file appears with the stored image that can then be decoded in the frontend.
Hope this is helpful to someone. Here is my code:

```
class ImageType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        filter_fields = {'product_id': ['exact'],
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

    base64file = graphene.String()

    def resolve_base64file(self, info):
        if self is not None and self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            if os.path.isfile(self.image.url):
                return base64.b64encode(self.image.read())
            else:
                return 'File not found'
        return ''
```

Comment: This is going to cause problems if/when you start storing your images on a server that's different from your actual web server.

Comment: Also, by passing the urls to the browser, you can allow the browser to use it's own cache to load the images faster. By loading them within the web app, you're forcing the browser to re-consume the resources over and over.

Comment: I understand, thank you. So how can I create an endopint where to get the image from the backend if I'm using graphql?

Comment: How does the client render the images? That's what would have to change.

Comment: It will be using React & Apollo. Depending on how I send it.

Comment: When you render the image element, use this value as the `src=` attribute for the `img` tag.